# Recursive list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to define a recursive list comprehension in Python?

Possibly a simplistic example, but something along the lines of:

```
nums = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
willThisWork = [x for x in nums if x not in self] # self being the current comprehension
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: If order is not an issue, `list(set(num))`. Otherwise, check `unique_everseen` in http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html.

Comment: leaky abstraction alert.  comprehensions shouldn't be thought of as loops, in my opinion, even though they may be implemented as loops in cpython ..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, there's no (documented, solid, stable, ...;-) way to refer to "the current comprehension".  You could just use a loop:

```
res = []
for x in nums:
  if x not in res:
    res.append(x)
```

of course this is very costly (O(N squared)), so you can optimize it with an auxiliary `set` (I'm assuming that keeping the order of items in `res` congruent to that of the items in `nums`, otherwise `set(nums)` would do you;-)...:

```
res = []
aux = set()
for x in nums:
  if x not in aux:
    res.append(x)
    aux.add(x)
```

this is enormously faster for very long lists (O(N) instead of N squared).

**Edit**: in Python 2.5 or 2.6, `vars()['_[1]']` might actually work in the role you want for `self` (for a non-nested listcomp)... which is why I qualified my statement by clarifying there's no **documented, solid, stable** way to access "the list being built up" -- that peculiar, undocumented "name" `'_[1]'` (deliberately chosen not to be a valid identifier;-) is the apex of "implementation artifacts" and any code relying on it deserves to be put out of its misery;-).

Comment: The set operations make it O(n log(n)), I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang sets in Python aren't implemented as red-black trees (like in STL), but use hashes instead as far as I know so it will be O(N).

Comment: @Justin is correct -- python sets and dicts are well-optimized hashes, with O(1) amortized cost for adding items and O(1) cost for lookups.

Answer (score 13):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), which gives the possibility to name the result of an expression, we could reference items already seen by updating a variable within the list comprehension:

```
# items = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
acc = []; [acc := acc + [x] for x in items if x not in acc]
# acc = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This:

- Initializes a list `acc` which symbolizes the running list of elements already seen
- For each item, this checks if it's already part of the `acc` list; and if not:

  - appends the item to `acc` (`acc := acc + [x]`) via an **assignment expression**
  - and at the same time uses the new value of `acc` as the mapped value for this item

Comment: Really neat, will definitely use in the future

Answer (score 10):

Actually you can! This example with an explanation hopefully will illustrate how.

define recursive example to get a number only when it is 5 or more and if it isn't, increment it and call the 'check' function again. Repeat this process until it reaches 5 at which point return 5.

```
print [ (lambda f,v: v >= 5 and v or f(f,v+1))(lambda g,i: i >= 5 and i or g(g,i+1),i) for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6] ]
```

result:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6]
>>>
```

essentially the two anonymous functions interact in this way:

```
let f(g,x) = {  
                 expression, terminal condition
                 g(g,x), non-terminal condition
             }

let g(f,x) = {  
                 expression, terminal condition
                 f(f,x), non-terminal condition
             }
```

make g,f the 'same' function except that in one or both add a clause where the parameter is modified so as to cause the terminal condition to be reached and then go
f(g,x) in this way g becomes a copy of f making it like:

```
f(g,x) = {  
                 expression, terminal condition
                 {
                    expression, terminal condition,
                    g(g,x), non-terminal codition
                 }, non-terminal condition
             }
```

You need to do this because you can't access the the anonymous function itself upon being executed.

i.e

```
(lambda f,v: somehow call the function again inside itself )(_,_)
```

so in this example let A = the first function and B the second. We call A passing B as f and i as v. Now as B is essentially a copy of A and it's a parameter that has been passed you can now call B which is like calling A.

This generates the factorials in a list

```
print [ (lambda f,v: v == 0 and 1 or v*f(f,v-1))(lambda g,i: i == 0 and 1 or i*g(g,i-1),i) for i in [1,2,3,5,6,7] ]

[1, 2, 6, 120, 720, 5040]
>>>
```

Comment: Cloning the lambda is unnecessary; you can use a generic proxy as the first lambda to allow any kind of second lambda to call itself.  `(lambda f,arg: f(f,arg))(lambda self,v: .... , firstvalue)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can write nested list comprehensions:

```
xs = [[i for i in range(1,10) if i % j == 0] for j in range(2,5)]
assert xs == [[2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9], [4, 8]]
```

From your code example, you seem to want to simply eliminate duplicates, which you can do with sets:

```
xs = sorted(set([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]))
assert xs == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

no. it won't work, there is no `self` to refer to while list comprehension is being executed.

And the main reason of course is that list comprehensions where not designed for this use.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But it looks like you are trying to make a list of the unique elements in nums.

You could use a `set`:

```
unique_items = set(nums)
```

Note that items in nums need to be hashable.

You can also do the following. Which is a close as I can get to your original idea. But this is not as efficient as creating a `set`.

```
unique_items = []
for i in nums:
    if i not in unique_items:
        unique_items.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
nums = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
set_of_nums = set(nums)
unique_num_list = list(set_of_nums)
```

or even this:

```
unique_num_list = sorted(set_of_nums)
```

Comment: The list comprehensions are unnecessary. `unique_num_list = list(set_of_nums)`. `sorted(set_of_nums)` returns a list.