# How can I access `self` of a dict comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x

basically I'm trying to calculate the sums of resources required in a recursive array with associate patterns...

here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
resources = { resource: resources.get( resource, 0 )+1 for resource in generator }
```

now of course the above code doesn't work because `resources` is unresolvable, but I want to access the dict as it's being created...
is there some way I can do this??

Comment: Are you just looking for a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Related, for list comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056466/3001761. Until the dictionary is completely created, it's not accessible.

Comment: thanks, that answers my question telling me it's not possible, but why was I downvoted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question. The answer is: you can't (or if you can, you shouldn't).

But there is a flaw in your idea (that's why I write this answer): you are using the wrong tool. I'm not talking of `collections.Counter`, but of functional tools. List comprehensions is a:

> a syntactic construct available in some programming languages for creating a list based on existing lists. *([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension))*

Here, you want to create a list based on an existing list **and on the current state of your list**. This could not be, by definition, a list comprehension by the book.

But there is another functional construction that is perfectly suitable for this case: the fold. A fold:

> through use of a given combining operation, recombine the results of recursively processing its constituent parts, building up a return value *([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)))*

In Python, you have to use the `reduce` function of the `functools` module:

```
>>> generator = (i%7 for i in range(20))
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda resources, resource: {**resources, resource: resources.get(resource, 0) + 1}, generator, {})
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 2}
```

The combining function takes the current dictionary and replaces the value associated to `resource` by the previous value + 1.

Of course, a regular loop would be okay too.

Comment: considering I already backtracked and did things differently, I'm marking this as an accepted answer for the `functools.reduce` solution, thank you :)

Comment: @Tcll You are welcome. I didn't expect any feedback on this answer. Thanks!