# Word frequency with dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I was trying to use a dictionary to count word frequency on a given string. Say:

```
s = 'I ate an apple a big apple'
```

I understand the best way to count word frequency is probably to use `collections.Counter`. But I want to know if I can solve this by using a dictionary comprehension.

My original method(without dictionary comprehension) was

```
dict = {}
for token in s.split(" "):
    dict[token] = dict.get(token, 0) + 1
```

and it works fine:

```
dict
{'I': 1, 'a': 1, 'an': 1, 'apple': 2, 'ate': 1, 'big': 1}
```

I tried to use a dictionary comprehension to this, like

```
dict = {}
dict = {token: dict.get(token, 0) + 1 for token in s.split(" ")}
```

But this didn't work.

```
dict
{'I': 1, 'a': 1, 'an': 1, 'apple': 1, 'ate': 1, 'big': 1}
```

What's wrong with the dictionary comprehension? Is it because I used itself inside the comprehension so every time I called `dict.get('apple', 0`) in the comprehension, I will get `0`? However, I don't know how to test this so I am not 100% sure.

P.S. If it makes any difference, I am using python 3.

Comment: This is what `collections.Counter` (a dict subtype) solved long ago

Comment: i wouldn't use dict as a variable name since it's a built in, you could break something by doing so

Comment: The variable `dict` isn't being updated until the comprehension is fully calculated, so `dict.get(token, 0)` inside the comprehension is only ever consulting the empty dictionary from the previous line.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Agreed, just want to dig into the mechanic behind dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through your code operation by operation, you will see what is wrong.

First you set `dict` to an empty dict. (As mentioned in the comments, it's a bad idea to use that for your own variable name, but that's not the problem here.)

Secondly, your dict comprehension is evaluated. At this point the name `dict` still refers to the empty dict. So every time you do `dict.get(whatever, 0)`, it will always get the default.

Finally, your populated dict is reassigned to the name `dict`, replacing the empty one that was previously there.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `list.count()`, as:

```
s = 'I ate an apple a big apple'

print  {token: s.split().count(token) for token in set(s.split())}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your dictionary comprehension to work, you need a reference to the comprehension inside itself. Something like this would work

```
{token: __me__.get(token, 0) + 1 for token in s.split(" ")}
```

if there were such thing as '`__me__`' referencing the comprehension being built. In Python 3 there is no a documented way to do this.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638524/6942134), an undocumented "implementation artifact" (on which Python users should not rely) can be used in Python 2.5, 2.6 to write self-referencing list comprehension. Maybe a similar hack exists for dictionary comprehensions in Python 3 too.