# Access the current list being built

Tags: python, list, indexing, self

I was working in Python and wondered if there was a to access the current list being built. Here is what I mean:

```py
def foo():
    return 10
def bar(baz):
    return baz * 2
list = [foo(), bar(this_list[0])]
```

Notice `this_list`. The output should be `20` because `foo` returns `10`, then is passed to `bar` which doubles it, getting `20`. How could I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638478/recursive-list-comprehension-in-python is similar to what I am asking, except it is list comp.

Comment: where is `this_list[0]` defined?

Comment: @FishingCode -- `this_list` is the list being made-- something like `self`.

Comment: `def bar()` is not setup to take it like that though.

Comment: @FishingCode -- I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I think it has to be two lines `list = [foo()]` then `list.append(bar(list[0]))`

Comment: No, it's not possible to access the list being built. What are you trying to achieve? Just avoiding a temporary variable?

Comment: @PeterWood -- Yeah, just wanted to see if it was possible.

Comment: Do you want it to be infinite?

Comment: @PeterPesch -- No

Comment: `list` is a bad name for a list. It hides the builtin name `list` which is used for creating lists.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you are trying to assign something to the variable `list` in a way that tries to use the contents of `list` itself. Yet, you haven't assigned any contents to `list` before trying to do this assignment, so the computer has no idea what "the contents of `list` itself" are supposed to be.

One can't reference the value of a variable before one puts a value inside the variable!

To achieve the desired effect, it's cleaner to simply do things step-by-step, in a "boring" way.

```
def foo():
    return 10
def bar(baz):
    return baz * 2

list = [foo()]
list.append(baz(list[0]))
```

Comment: Or `a = foo(); values = [a, baz(a)]`